# Use List Metadata With Standard Fields?

Tags: metadata-api, standard-objects, fields, ant, list-metadata

## Question

Is there any way to retrieve the "list" details, which include the field id for standard fields?

## Background

I'm building a report on picklist values by record type and am including links to the fields to allow quick editing. I'm getting this with a list metadata for the custom field type. However, I also need to get the values for standard picklist fields, i.e. `Account.Industry`. With other list calls, the standard values are returned with the custom, i.e. listing custom objects will return the Account object. However, it doesn't seem like that applies the same way to custom fields.

Is this a hole in the list metadata calls? Or am I missing something obvious in the docs?

Comment: I don't know if they have field Ids somewhere that you can use, or if they are exposed in the metadata API but if you inspect the URL on the setup pages for standard fields you'll notice their Id parameter is the same as their API name. e.g. `https://eu2.salesforce.com/p/setup/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Industry&‌​type=Lead`. Could you use this information to construct your links instead?

Comment: Interesting, that looks like it might just be the ticket, thanks @AlexTennant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if they have field Ids somewhere behind the scenes that you can use, or if they are exposed in the metadata API.

However, if you inspect the URL on the setup pages for standard fields you'll notice their Id parameter is the same as their API name and their type parameter is the object's API name.

```
/setup/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=[Field API Name]&‌​‌​type=[Object API Name]
```

e.g. for the Industry field on Lead the setup URL is as follows:

```
/setup/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Industry&‌​‌​type=Lead
```

In the absence of field Ids you should be able to build your URLs using these two parameters.

The Record Type specific page however use a URL parameter called `pt` and are of the form:

```
/setup/ui/recordtypefieldedit.jsp?id=[Record Type Id]&pt=[PT 'Id']
```

Unfortunately I can't find anywhere that those `pt` 'Id's are exposed or a way to avoid needing to use them.

You can construct a URL for the page preceding the actual picklist selection page using the following, but that is not ideal if you want a link directly to the picklist page.

```
/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id=[Record Type Id]&type=[Object API Name]
```

It is worth noting however that these `pt` values do appear to be consistent across Orgs and across objects (which makes sense as the picklist values for some of them are shared), here are some examples:

**Lead**

- Rating = 2
- Industry = 4
- Salutation = 8
- LeadSource = 9

**Contact**

- Salutation = 8
- LeadSource = 9

**Account**

- Ownership = 1
- Rating = 2
- Type = 3
- Industry = 4
- AccountSource = 9

**Opportunity**

- LeadSource = 9
- Type = 10

Comment: so it looks like they do have ids in some cases, this works great for the field details, but in other spots Account.Industry has an id of "4", e.g. https://na5.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypefieldedit.jsp?id=012700000009fZr&pt=4

Comment: @Ralph Unfortunately I can't find anywhere that those `pt` Ids are exposed or a way around using them. You can construct a URL for the page preceding the actual picklist selection page using `/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id=[Record Type Id]&type=[Object API Name]` but that is not ideal.